# Meteor probability question, assuming that at most one meteor can fall or more than one meteor can fall

Tags: probability

I know there have been similar questions on Math SE, but this has been bothering me for quite a while. Let's say you have the following question, but solve it with two different assumptions:

> In the first hour, there is a $10\%$ chance that a meteor will fall into Earth. Assuming that the probability is uniform throughout (not too sure how to say this properly, but I'm trying to say that a meteor has equal chance of falling at any time), what is the probability that a meteor falls within the first $30$ minutes?

The two assumptions are:

1. More than $1$ meteor can fall into Earth within that one hour
2. At most $1$ meteor can fall into Earth within that one hour

Solving the problem with assumption 1:

> Let the probability of a meteor falling within the first hour be $p$. Then, we can set up the following equation: $$\begin{align}P(\text{none fall in first 30 mins.})+P(\text{none fall in last 30 mins.)}&=P(\text{none fall in first hour})\\(1-p)^2&=0.9\\p&\approx5.13\%\end{align}$$

Solving with assumption 2:

> Let the probability of a meteor falling within the first hour be $p$. Then, we can set up the following equation: $$\begin{align}P(\text{one falls in first 30 mins.})+P(\text{one falls in last 30 mins.)}-P(\text{one falls in each 30 minute intervals})&=P(\text{one falls in first hour})\\p+p-p^2&=0.1\\p&\approx5.13\%\end{align}$$

I feel like the two assumptions should produce different answers, but I can't pinpoint where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer re the 2nd assumption is wrong.

There is a $10\%$ chance of the meteor falling in 1 hour.

If this meteor falls in the 1st 30 minutes, then, by the 2nd assumption, it is impossible for a 2nd meteor to fall anytime within the hour.

So, the events that a meteor falls within the 1st 30 minutes and a meteor falls within the 2nd 30 minutes are :

- not independent, so $p(E_1, E_2) \neq p(E_1) \times p(E_2).$
- **and** actually disjoint, and therefore **additive**

So, there is a $5\%$ chance of the meteor falling within the 1st 30 minutes and a $5\%$ chance of the meteor falling within the 2nd 30 minutes.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally switched the solutions for the two assumptions.

Comment: So is it that assumption 2 is wrong? (see edit on the post)

Comment: @AidenChow I have edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, it is obvious now.

Comment: @user2661923 What if I said P(1 meteor in 1 hour) = P(your meteor is only in 2nd 30 min interval) + P (meteor is only in 1st 30 min interval). Let x = P(meteor in 30 mins interval) .  1/10 = x(1-x) + x(x-1). You will get the 5.13% and 1-5.13% but only 1 is right. Why?

Comment: @JamesHuang No, the math of $x(1-x)$ assumes that the two events are **independent**.  Disjoint events are **not independent**.  See [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Comment: Your suggested alternate premise implies that the events are disjoint, and that therefore, the analysis in my answer, for the 2nd assumption in your question pertains.  That is $5\% + 5\% = 10\%.$

Comment: Another way of saying the same thing, is that the math should be $10\% = [x(1 - 0) + x(1 - 0)] = 2x \implies x = 5\%.$  This follows because (for example) if the meteor falls in the first 30 minutes, the chance of it **not falling** in the 2nd 30 minutes is $(1 - 0) = 1$, rather than $(1 - x).$

Comment: @user2661923 bruh thats actually smart i totally forgot. that makes so much sense, thank you my guy